# How to debug a system app with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I have inherited an Android project without having much idea about the development on this platform. First I want to explain why I want to debug a system app if you have any idea about the problem:

This project is a system app and has to change `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE`'s value. Now the customer has problems with this feature and wants to solve it.

- The device is Android 5.1 with manufacturer's special permissions and the APK file is in system/priv-app folder.
- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />` is in AndroidManifest.xml.
- I get this exception: "Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS".

In the main actitvity this condition is checked:

```
public boolean isSystemApp() {
    return (getApplicationInfo().flags & (ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM | 
            ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP)) != 0;
}
```

**So I want to debug the system app running it in the system/priv-app to have privileges. Is it posible?**